# multiple records with the same order id incremented from the previous MAX value

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Sorry if this was asked before. I can't find it.

I have a table **Orders** like this:

```
`id | orderId | productId`
```

Order may have multiple products but they all should have the same order Id.
In code I do:
    
    `int nextOrder=db.Orders.Max(m=>m.orderId)+1;//???!!!!
    foreach(var p in productList)
    {
        var o=new Order();
        o.orderId=nextOrder;//???????????????????
        o.productId=p.productId;
        db.Orders.Add(o);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();`

However this is not thread safe - when I process one order, another thread may get the same order Id. How do I fix this to insert multiple records with the same order id incremented from the previous MAX value?
Thank you!

Comment: You should add the products to a collection `order.Products` and EF will do the rest. (Since Order has an auto-increment column as you say below).

Comment: @Gert Arnold I was hoping to avoid creating another table **order** because I have no properties related to the whole order.

Comment: So what's the use of it? It's nothing but an incrementing Id value relating to nothing. Normally this model would consist of three tables, `Order`, `Product` and a junction table connecting both in a many-to-many relationship (your table).

Comment: @Gert Arnold my example is just an example. What I have is a collection of items, and I wanted to keep it as 'row_id | collection_id | item_data' in a single table.

Comment: what you and Mad Myche seems to be saying is I need two tables **Collections** and **CollectionItems**

Comment: I can implement what I want by using GUID for collectionId (OrderId) but I've heard it's not a good idea...

Answer (score 1):

You can write such logic at database side using either trigger or stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has an `IDENTIITY` column function available, MS Access and MySql have similar known as `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Something like this could be implemented on your orders table; it would be auto populated when you insert a new record, and you could call another SQL command to retrieve that value.

The Sql Server version of this would be in this format

`INSERT Orders (columns) VALUES (new values); SELECT Scope_Identity();`

MySql, MS Access and other RDBMS would have similar commands as well.

> > Update

Many commerce platforms would have the Orders and Items in at least 2 separate tables, usually Order would be the order information and OrderItem would be the items within an order. Usually you would want more information of the product within the OrderItem table due to prices changing etc, which shouldn't retroactively change an order from the past whe you update (or delete) a product in the future. Here is a rough outline for the database, in quasi-code. If you are using and ORM such as Entity Framework you may be able to add the OrderItem in as a Collection as a property of the Order class.

```
Order
    OrderID        Int      AutoIncrement   Primary Key
    OrderDate      DateTime
    OrderSubtotal  Decimal
    ...etc...

 OrderItem
    ItemID         Int      AutoIncrement
    OrderID        Int      Indexed, FK relationship to Order.OrderID
    ProductID      Int
    ProductPrice   Decimal
    Qty            Int
    ...etc...
```

Comment: I use Auto Increment for ID column, but for Order Id I need to insert several records with the same OrderId value

Comment: The items contained within the order should be in a separate table, we'll call it OrderItems. I will update the answer to show an idea of how it should look

Comment: yeah I figured that. I was hoping to avoid creating another table because I have no properties related to the whole order. But thank you for your answer

Comment: Think of a receipt from the store, there is a date, total, taxes etc at the top and bottom, and the inside is filled with the items purchased. I would be more than happy to help

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. My example was a little misleading probably. What I have is a collection of items, and I wanted to keep it as 'row_id | collection_id | item_data' in a single table. I  can implement that by using GUID for collectionId (OrderId) but I've heard it's not a good idea...

Comment: It is fine as a collection, but you would want to keep it (items) separate. If it should grow once it can be a burden to query. One of the sites I built is doing $50K daily on items with an average price under $10.